# Avoid data base open when excel is running

Tags: excel, database, vb.net

I developed a vb.net program that uses excel file to generate some reports. 
Once the program takes too much time to generate a report, I usually do other things while the program is running. The problem is that sometimes I need to open other excel files and the excel files used in the program are shown to me. I want to still hide those files being processed even when I run other excel files. Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [`FileSystem.Lock` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.lock) controls access by other processes to all or part of a file opened by using the `Open` function.

The `My` feature gives you better productivity and performance in file I/O operations than `Lock` and `Unlock`. For more information, see [FileSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem).

More information [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=file%20locking%20windows%20vb.net).